# Can Terraria host servers run games using mods?

Tags: terraria

If there is a mod installed on two Terraria clients on two different computers, can one client host a server while the other joins with the mod working?

For example:

My friend and I both have the Obsidian mod, but we usually play in single-player mode. We would like to play the mod on multiplayer. Can he host a server and have me be able to join?

Comment: While it does appear to be possible using a tConfig server, I can't figure out how...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is certainly possible. You both just need to have the same mods active.

However, you say you're using the Obsidian mod, and from what I remember there is a part of that mod that is strictly single-player only (specifically, the Parallel Worlds pack), so it may not work as you want it to.
Otherwise, running mods in multiplayer is fine.